# Creating index for both equality and timestamp range queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, date-range

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    session_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    session_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    session_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    site_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    photo_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    uuid TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX sessions_lookup ON sessions (
    site_id, photo_id, uuid, session_start, session_end
)
```

And I need to run queries of this type against it:

```
SELECT session_id
FROM sessions
WHERE site_id = %s
AND photo_id = %s
AND uuid = %s
AND %s <@ tsrange(
            session_start - interval '3 hours',
            session_end + interval '3 hours'
          )
```

There's different variations of the range query part (check seperately for both session_start and session_end, use `OVERLAPS`, etc. but as far as I have tested they all do the same thing).

Using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I get the following results (using actual values instead of placeholders):

```
 Index Scan using sessions_lookup on sessions  (cost=0.00..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.062..0.063 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((site_id = 10113150) AND (photo_id = 10240980) AND (uuid = '042d6f26-e298-0140-a4cc-7bfd0f9ccd27'::text))
   Filter: (((session_start - '03:00:00'::interval) <= '2014-09-05 09:45:38'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((session_end + '03:00:00'::interval) >= '2014-09-05 09:45:38'::timestamp without time zone))
 Total runtime: 1.384 ms
(4 rows)
```

*Subsequent runs give ~0.080ms query runtime.*

Ideally, I would like to use the index as part of the timestamp lookup, but it seems to be completely ignored (same result with or without it in the index). Do I need to alter the order of fields or am I doing something wrong (do I need a different type of index)?

This is tested on a table with 45k records, but if need be I can create a bigger sample set.

Comment: I don't think that `<@` is btree-indexable, and even if there was a suitable GiST index here I don't think a bitmap index scan is (a) possible in this case or (b) likely to help performance wise anyway. Though it's interesting that `<@` is being decomposed into range range predicates that *are* potentially b-tree indexable; I wasn't aware that was actually possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thoughts: the [`OVERLAPS` *operator*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) is working like the overlap (`&&`) [range operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html). The containment (`<@` and variants) operator is a little different, but if you want to test whether a single time-point is within a (date-)time range, they work similar.

The reason behind your query can't use your index is, that you didn't test your columns directly within your query. You test a range *expression*, which is created by using your columns. In these cases, you can usually set up an [expression based index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html), but in your case, that won't help either (already mentioned by [@CraigRinger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037474/creating-index-for-both-equality-and-timestamp-range-queries#comment40787310_26037474)).

If we can forget a bit about ranges and overlapping, here it is your `WHERE` clause:

```
(session_start - interval '3 hours' <= '2014-09-05 09:45:38') AND
(session_end + interval '3 hours' >= '2014-09-05 09:45:38')
```

Let's do a little math:

```
(session_start <= '2014-09-05 09:45:38'::timestamp + interval '3 hours') AND
(session_end >= '2014-09-05 09:45:38'::timestamp - interval '3 hours')
```

This will now use your index.

With parameters:

```
SELECT session_id
FROM sessions
WHERE site_id = %s
AND photo_id = %s
AND uuid = %s
AND (session_start <= %s::timestamp + interval '3 hours')
AND (session_end >= %s::timestamp - interval '3 hours')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af4c7/1)

Comment: I did some tests and came to the same conclusion - I basically have to use the raw column values and manipulate the given timestamp to fit instead for good performance (which is not an issue, just have to do it client-side instead of in SQL).

As an added bonus I can add session_id to the end for an Index Only Scan, which is still only 1/7th of the table size despite containing a lot of fields. It all counts :)